# Redis Lua Doesn't Recognize Inf?

Tags: lua, redis

I'm writing a Lua script in Redis, and have one line that's breaking everything:

```
local to_remove = redis.call('ZRANGE', KEYS[1], -5, "+inf")
```

Returns:

```
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: Error running script (call to f_f1d95d2e103f00220a476f0ef2a2abc798682c55): ERR value is not an integer or out of range
```

This goes away completely if I replace "+inf" with any number. I've tried "inf" and "-inf" as well, and none of these work. Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind. I'm an idiot. Should have just used "-1" in place of "inf." ZRANGE just doesn't support inf, and -1 gives the same results I would have expected from inf. Hopefully this helps someone trying to do the same later on.